# Where are Thunderbird/CardBook log files stored?

Tags: thunderbird

I am trying to debug a problem with the Thunderbird CardBook extension connecting to a CardDav server. The CardBook configuration allows me to configure Debug Mode (turned it on) and the number of lines kept in the log file (set it to 500). Unfortunately I am too stupid to find that log (and my Google fu is weak).

The Thunderbird Error Console does not display anything related to CardBook.

So, where do these log messages go?

Answer (score 2):

The CardBook log can be accessed via a double click on the status line. This will open a new window which displays the log messages.

(Sorry, I discovered this just now, after I already had asked the question.)

(I tried to add a screenshot but imgur claims it is invalid. :-( )

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create your own protocol log

Create a batch file by copying the lines below and paste them into the notepad application, and save the file as "create_imap_log.bat". Variables must not contain quotation marks.

**windows**

> set MOZ_LOG=IMAP:5,timestamp
>
> set MOZ_LOG_FILE=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\imap.log
>
> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"

For more Explanation please follow link below

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Windows

Comment: No, this didn't work, but I found out how to access the log I needed. See my own answer.